# Замена слово/значение в текстовом файле

Tags: c++, linux, строки

Cтолкнулся с такой проблемой,мне необходимо изменить значение в строке(которую находит с помощью ключа). Проблема в том, что мне неизвестно это значение. Нахожу строку с помощью ключа, но не удаётся изменить значение, которое идёт последовательно после этого ключа, также как эту строку записать обратно в исходный файл.Буду очень признателен за советы и помощь!

```
void checkfile(string password,string login,string sum)
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("base.txt");
    ofstream fout("replaced.txt");

    for (string line; !fin.eof(); getline(fin, line))
    {
        string sin(line.substr(line.find("=") + 1));
        if (line.find(login) != string::npos)
        {
            if (line.find(password) != string::npos)
            {
                 line.replace(line.find(password)+1, sum.size(), sum);
            }
        }
        fout << line << '\n';
    }
    fin.close();
}
```

В base.txt  записано строки так :

```
str str123 0
hello world 0
...
(Мне надо именно  3 значение менять)
```

Comment: Если размер после изменения будет меняться, то лучше сразу делать замены, переписывая файл в новый. Потом можно сделать rename

Comment: @avp, здравствуйте) Да, будет меняться. Хорошо, но  у меня это тоже является небольшой проблемой,так как раньше такой опыт не получал, но это я попытаюсь сам справится, а вот с заменой...

Comment: Непонятно, что вы хотите - у вас в файле нет никаких символов =. Вы не могли бы описать словами понятнее, что именно менять, как именно обрабатывать строки. И попутно - я бы не использовал имя `sin` - вдруг потом придется математику использовать :), да и проверка на конец файла делается не так.

Comment: а вы хотите читать из одного и записать в другой файл? зачем вам другой файл, если вы хотите провести изменение в исходном? Что то я не очень понел ваши намерения

Comment: Еще один вариант именно *перезаписи* - если в файле есть вариант строк-комментариев (скажем, начинаются с `#` - то вы можете удалять старую строку, комментируя ее, а потом дописывать в конец файла новую. В этом случае время от времени следует выполнять "сжатие" - выбрасывая лишние закомментированные строки.

Comment: @Mikhailo, в этом и заключается сложность, что без использование прочих разделителей. Необходимо менять значение   '0'(оно может быть совсем иным) определенной строки,которой определяется с помощью ключей: login && password.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, если честно, я не занимался этим раньше, по-этому и возникла сложность. Нет, мне необходимо изменять в исходном, без разницы  местоположения строки, так как поиск данных идёт по-всему файлу, и позиция строки не имеет значения. Я просто много читал, и как понимаю, это реализуется с помощью временного файла, либо записью в другой файл. По-этому, я так и пробовал реализовать. Если это можно реализовать проще, то я бы желал это узнать.

Comment: @Alex, то что вы делали (например, с временным файлом) это самый простой и поэтому правильный способ

Comment: @avp,благодарю за ваш  совет. Решил данную проблему. У меня есть ещё одна проблема, которая для меня является  более сложной,и мне бы хотелось узнать, какими вариантами  можно её решить. Здесь её задать? ( Это уже связанная с массив строк)..

Comment: @Alex, на этом сайте (SO) принято для каждой новой проблемы делать новый вопрос

Comment: @avp,здравствуйте. Извините за наглость, но смогли бы ли вы,  посоветовать, как  реализовать цикл для сравнения. Я сделал пост, вот ссылка: "https://goo-gl.su/fozOx".  Мне просто не удаётся  сделать сравнение с cтроковым типом данных.

Comment: [rc = strcmp(s1, s2)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) возвращает rc < 0, если s1 меньше s2; rc == 0, если s1 и s2 равны; rc > 0, если s1 больше s2 (символы сравниваются, как [unsigned](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/strcmp.c)). / Т.о. надо написать `if(strcmp(logfile,login) == 0)
  {
     cout << "Данные совпадают." << endl;
  }`

Comment: @avp, а разве можно использовать strcmp()  для переменных типа string?

Comment: @Alex, конечно нет (но по вашей ссылке я вижу `char logfile[100];
char logpass[100];` ... `strcmp(logfile,login)` (наверное login тоже `char *`)) // А причем тут string? Если использовать strcmp со string, то из string надо взять [.c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)

Comment: @avp,простите за неправильное формулирования предложения. У меня изначально была проблема с записью в массив строк, но мне посоветовали использовать string. И я  решил эту проблему с помощью советов более опытных людей в этой ситуации, но  я не учёл того, что может  произойти сложность с циклом сравнения. Пробовал решить эту проблему, но так мне не удалось, поэтому и обратился к вам. И за что, мне очень неудобно.

Comment: @Alex, вообще-то string можно сравнивать, используя операции `==`, `>` и `<`. Т.е. на C++ можно написать `string s1, s2; cin >> s1 >> s2; if (s1 < s2) cout << "Less\n";` / Вы книжки какие-нибудь по С++ прочли?

Comment: @avp, я не на таком уровне, чтобы не знать такие вещи. Я же уточнил, что проблема заключается в цикле. А так, я сравниваю их операцией: `==`.

Comment: @Alex, вряд ли у [Мыщхъа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8) есть **учебник** С++ (вот какой-то учебник, лучше наверное от автора языка, неплохо бы прочесть, прежде чем начинать использовать язык)

Comment: @avp,если вы могли бы посоветовать книгу, то я бы обязательно ней поинтересовался. А так, не особо приятно, что вы меня считаете на таком низком уровне. Не удивлюсь, если вы посчитали, что я не знаю базового синтаксиса.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98942/discussion-between-alex-and-avp).

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас могут быть разные строки - с чем-то лишним или нехваткой (не ровно три слова), то я бы делал через строчный поток.

```
void checkfile(string password, string login, string sum) {
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("base.txt");
    ofstream fout("replaced.txt");

    for (string line; getline(fin, line);) {
        istringstream in(line);
        string l, p;

        if (in >> l >> p && l == login && p == password) {
            fout << l << " " << p << " " << sum << '\n';
            }
        else
            fout << line << "\n";  // Старая строка
        }

    fin.close();
    }
```

Я добавил вывод неизмёненной строки, не знаю, у вас его нет.

Если есть гарантия, что в каждой строке в файле ровно три слова - то можно проще:

```
void checkfile(string password, string login, string sum) {
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("base.txt");
    ofstream fout("replaced.txt");

    for (string l, p, s; fin >> l >> p >> s;) {
        if (l == login && p == password) {
            fout << l << " " << p << " " << sum << "\n";
            }
        else
            fout << l << " " << p << " " << s << "\n";  // Старая строка
        }

    fin.close();
    }
```

Просто проверять наличие логина и пароля, по-моему, мало - вдруг у кого-то логин, как пароль, а пароль, как логин у кого-то другого?

Comment: Да, вы правы, но я и по-этому делал  проверку и логина и пароля, чтобы сократить вероятность совпадения. Но, всё же, это тоже не особо понижает риск. Но увы, работа с файлами у меня недостаточно опыта, по-этому,я делал то, что мне под силам. И вот, почему я и задал этот вопрос. Чтобы узнать , что неправильно, как лучше.  Да и вообще, услышать/увидеть  рассуждения более  грамотных людей в этом.

Answer (score 1):

1. Аргументы функции не нужно копировать, и нужно указать,
   что они не меняются, также нужно иметь возможность использовать
   временные переменные, поэтому передайте по константной ссыльке.
2. Передайте в вашу функцию также имя файла или сам файловый обьект,
   для удобства дальнейшего использования функции.

Абсолютно не нужно иметь дополнительные обьекты для хранения того, что прочитали. Достаточно зафиксировать позицию, где нам нужно остновиться, а потом работать с этого места. А если хотите заменить в файле что то, то откройте его и для чтения и для записи Это покажу на примере:

```
void 
checkfile(std::fstream& fout, const std::string& password, 
    const std::string& login, const std::string& sum)
{   
   //проверка на открытие файла выполняется 
   //до вызова функции или выпоняйте здесь
    std::string s1, s2;
    std::streampos pos = 0;
    while (fout >> s1 >> s2) {
        if (s1 == login && s2 == password) {
            //игнорирум все пробелы 
            while (fout.peek() == ' ') fout.ignore();
            //получим текущую позицию чтения
            pos = fout.tellg();
            //установим позицию для записи начиная от pos 
            fout.seekp(pos, std::ios::beg);
            //и запиываем нашу строку
            fout << sum;
            /*(можете заппомнить эту позицию для
            дальнейшей записи там старой  строки)
            дальше игнорируем всю оставшуюся строку
            и переходим на следующую */
            fout.ignore(100, '\n');
        }
    }
    fout.close();   
}
```

Comment: Гм, у автора вопроса два *разных* файла - для чтения и записи. Но даже если вы решили усовершенствовать вопрос :) - то перезапись одного и того же файла чревата неприятностями, если записываемая информация по размеру не совпадает с перезаписываемой... Это хорошо работает с бинарными файлами и записями фиксированного размера...

Comment: @Harry, я ничего не решил, я допускаю, что  имею дело с мыслящими людьми, а не с людьми, которым нужен готовый код. В ответе важна логика того, как добиться результата. Откуда и куда записать дело десятое, и давайте не будем говорить, что в коде еще не хватает обработка ошибок или  другие подробности....

Comment: @Harry, насчёт двух разных файлов, я выше объяснил почему. Насчёт, перезаписи одного и того же файла согласен  с вами. Я пытался так сделать, но почему-то не происходили изменения . Даже, данный момент, используя совет AR Hovsepyan, мне не удаётся изменить файл. Я предполагаю ,что причина является,  как вы и сказали, проблема с размером. Но, как эту проблему можно решить?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, очень признателен за ваши слова. Я  пробовал разобраться с вашим вариантом реализации данной проблемы. И вот, я столкнулся с той же проблемой, которой изначально я сталкивался. В случаи работы с тем же файлом, у меня не происходят никакие изменения. Я бы хотел узнать причину, и как это можно решить?